# How can i give permissions to only two users , but the other users will not be visible on the "share with" page?

Tags: permissions, item-level-permissions, custom-permission-level

I want to see only two users to give permission from the list. thr others should not be visible. ıs there a way to do it?[image]

Comment: Are you breaking permission on page and then giving permission to those two users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unfortunately,** you can't limit the number of users who should be shown in the `Invite People` Textbox to specific users.

This `Invite People` shows all people in **your organization** and only the specified people in this text box will be granted to the provided permissions in `Show Options` section.